# задача подсчёта количества ошибок в тексте

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

вводится текст со стандратного ввода вывода, нужно найти количество ошибок.
Ошибкой считается если 1) первая буква в предложении строчная 2) в слове на любом месте кроме первого символа слова стоит заглавная буква.
Предложение заканчивается либо точкой либо вопросительным знаком, либо восклицательным, словом считается любая последовательность латинских символов.
Задача с acm.timus http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1038 .

Мой алгоритм такой: читать символ за символом и при встече ".", "!", либо "?" делать проверку предложения на наличие вышеупомянутых ошибок.

проблем в том, что отправляя не сервер выдаётся Wroung Answer 2 , это значит что либо неверный алгоритм либо реализация, проверял на всевозможных тестах всегда получаю правильный ответ. Какие ещё тесты придумать незнаю, помогите найти ошибку в моём решении.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    deque<char> sent;
    char c = 0;
    size_t count = 0;
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        c = getchar();
        if (c != '.' && c != '?' && c != '!')
        {
            sent.push_back(c);
        }
        else
        {
            // предложение закончилось, sent содержит текущее предложение
            for (size_t i = 0; i < sent.size(); ++i)
            {           
                if (isalpha(sent[i]))
                {
                   // проверяем первую в предложении букву на на строчную 
                    if (islower(sent[i]))
                        count++;
                    break;
                }
            }

            string word;
            // в переменной word лежит текущее слово
            for (size_t i = 0; i < sent.size() + 1; ++i)
            {
                if (i < sent.size() && isalpha(sent[i]))
                {                   
                    word.push_back(sent[i]);
                }
                else
                {                        
                    // проверка каждого слова на ошибки 
                    for (size_t l = 1; l < word.size(); l++)
                    {
                        if (isalpha(word[l]) && !islower(word[l]))
                        {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    // опусташаем word для следующего в предложении слова
                    word.clear();
                }
            }

            //cout << count << endl;
            // опусташаем sent для следующего в тексте предложения
            sent.clear();
        }
    } 

    cout << count;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: На мой взгляд то, что написано, вообще не имеет смысла.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow что именно не имеет смысла??? вы бы аргументировали и по конкретнее говорили

Comment: В том, что это просто надо выбросить в помойное ведро. Нельзя так писать код. Код никакого смысла для читающего его не имеет. Нужно писать код так, чтобы о намерениях программиста было ясно читающему.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow не буду я ничего выбрасывать, код простой, отступы везде поставил всё читается, если что то не понятно то тут проблема в читающем этот код. и алгоритм я описал, остальное дело техники

Comment: @VladfromMoscow я для вас комментарии раставил

Comment: Алгоритм не полон. Как минимум, Вы не учитываете пробелы, цифры и т.п. символы (разделители) которые могут быть как между словами, так и перед первым словом. / И задайтесь вопросом -- если предложение начинается, например, с числа, то является ли первое за ним слово первым словом в предложении.

Comment: @avp всмысле не учитываете ? я же написал в посте что является ошибкой в задаче, если перед первым словом в предложении стоит всё кроме буквы то игнорируем до тех пор пока не встретиться буква. В слово это последовательность только латинских букв. Разделители могут встретиться и я это проверяю Здесьб `if (isalpha(word[l]) && !islower(word[l]))
                        {
                            count++;
                        } else // не буква`

Comment: @avp да, если предложение начинается с цифры то первое за ним слово это первое слово в предложениее.

Comment: Вместо споров, запустите простой тест: ` abc. abc` Результат будет 0. / (Все остальные ошибки ищите сами, мой совет -- пересмотрите алгоритм, накапливать все предложение тут вообще не нужно, можно вообще обойтись анализом очередного прочитанного символа)

Comment: @avp почему результат 0 ? первая буква (A)  строчная в предложении а это ошибка, ответ 2 потому что следующее предложение тоже с маленькой начинается

Comment: Вы это логически вывели или **увидели на экране**? / Кстати, добавьте вывод `\n` в `cout << count;`

Comment: @avp увидел на экране, раскоментировав строчку `//cout << count << endl;` после второго for цикла, это тот же вывод просто он вызывается в "реальном времени" для отладки скажем так.

Comment: @avp а предложения я не накапливаю, а проверяю их одно за другим, sent хранит текущее предложение, после анализа его на ошибки, sent очищается и тоже самое для следующего предложения... возможно вы правы по поводу смены алгоритма на посимвольный анализ, но это для меня кажется сложнее с точки зрения реализации

Comment: Ну, да, буквоед Вы наш и спорщик (двоечник наверное?). Накапливаете Вы слова в предложении. Посимвольная реализация нисколько не сложнее, а может даже проще. Смотрите в ответе, сейчас набросаю код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ловите.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int sentence_begin = 1, cnterr = 0, c = 0, i;

  while (c != EOF) {
    // skip delimiters
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && !isalpha(c)) 
      if (c == '.' || c == '?' || c == '!')
        sentence_begin++;
    if (c != EOF) {
      // read the word, here first letter in c
      i = 0; // letter position in the word
      do {
        if (sentence_begin) { // first letter in the first word
          sentence_begin = 0;
          if (!isupper(c))
            cnterr++;
        } 
        if (i++ && isupper(c)) // not first letter in any word
          cnterr++;
      } while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && isalpha(c));
      if (c == '.' || c == '?' || c == '!')
        sentence_begin++;
    }
  }

  cout << cnterr << '\n';
}
```

Что непонятно, спрашивайте (а в принципе, мы уже IMHO все выяснили в моих комментариях под Вашим вопросом).

Comment: спасибо за код, но зачем второй `(c = fgetc(stdin))` ? тоесть зачем два раза читать символ из stdin ? что это даёт ?

Comment: В первом (из 2-х вложенных во внешний `while (c != EOF)`) циклов  мы читаем разделители. После выхода из него в переменной `c` первая буква слова. Во втором цикле `do { ... } while (c = fgetc(...))`  мы сначала анализируем букву, а в конце цикла читаем следующую и тут же проверяем, а не разделитель ли это? Кстати, именно поэтому удвоена проверка на разделитель, который завершает предложение. / Как видите каждый символ stdin читается один раз (а не два).